# Jquery Progressbar with countdown timer

Tags: jquery

Ive been searching high and low and was just wondering if it was possible to make the Jquery UI Progressbar interact with this piece of code.

Jquery Progress bar found here > http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar/

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#jQueryProgressbar1').countDown({
    targetDate: {
        'day':  25,
        'month': 12,
        'year': 2011,
        'hour': 0,
        'min':  0,
        'sec':  0
      }     
});
```

Basically the ui progressbar will read the day, month, year etc from the code and intergrate that with the progressbar's bar display......kinda like a countdown timer but with the progressbar.

Comment: what countdown script are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work? ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Hyvqv/))

```
var target = new Date('12/25/2011'),
    today = new Date(),
    daysToGo = Math.ceil((target.getTime() - today.getTime() ) / (1000*60*60*24)),
    // probably not the best, but it should work
    percent = 100 - daysToGo;

$("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: percent,
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-progressbar').append(daysToGo + ' days left!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, it works great! just one more thing....would it be possible to get it to say in percentage instead of 'days left? for example - 75% complete ?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know how you wanted to calculate the percent, what number is 0%? The way it is above, basically 0% equals 100 days. So if you use something like 80 (today), then use this `percent = 100 - parseInt( (daysToGo / 80) * 100, 10);`

Comment: wow! thats awesome! Thank you! you really know your stuff! Is there anyway for it to work like a countdown timer would work? you set the date/month/year and it would recognise todays date/month and work out the percentage untill the date/month/year that is set (example 12/25/2011) ?

Comment: @Scott that is what it does, you just need to refresh the page before it will update - which happens at midnight on your computer. Go look at that demo again, it will say 79 days for today. If you mean a countdown with minutes and seconds, then I'd suggest using a countdown timer plugin. There aren't enough pixels to have the progress bar update for each hour.

Comment: Thank you ever so much fudgey, i appreciate your time :)